# A proof of a theorem in Real and Complex analysis of W.Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> $Theorem$ Let $\mu$ be a complex borel measure in $\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)=\mu((-\infty,x])$.Then $f'(x)=A$ if and only if $\forall \epsilon >0,\exists \delta>0$
>   such that for every interval $I$ that contains $x$  for which $m(I)<\delta$,we have that $|\frac{\mu(I)}{m(I)}-A|<\epsilon$.

$m$ denotes the lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}$

I found this theorem in Real and Complex Analysis of W.Rudin without a proof and i did not manage to find a proof of it somewhere else.

I also tried to prove it my self but i did not come up with anything.

Can someone find a proof for this statement?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

$$f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\mu((-\infty,x+h])-\mu((-\infty,x])}{h}\\= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\mu([x,x+h])}{m([x,x+h])}$$